# Not able to pass values to Detailed fragment in android

Tags: android, interface, fragment

I have integrated two fragments in one activity. one fragment is having expandable list view and another fragment having details about the selected item from the list. As i know, without activity we could not pass the values from one activity to another. so i have created Interface in list fragment and add following code.

```
    OnItemSelectedListener mCallback;

public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(int menuID, String sShortDesc, String sDescription, double dRate);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

    mCallback = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;

}
```

and on item selected event i have added following code.

```
            mCallback.onItemSelected(oALMenu.get(groupPosition).getCategoryMenuItem().get(childPosition).getMenuID() , oALMenu.get(groupPosition).getCategoryMenuItem().get(childPosition).getItemShortDesc(),oALMenu.get(groupPosition).getCategoryMenuItem().get(childPosition).getDescription(), oALMenu.get(groupPosition).getCategoryMenuItem().get(childPosition).getRate());
```

Now, i have implemented interface in my main activity and implemented method as below.

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(int menuID, String sShortDesc, String sDescription, double dRate) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Detail_Fragment oDetail_Fragment = (Detail_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_Details);
    System.out.println (">> " + oDetail_Fragment);
    System.out.println(">> " + menuID + " >> " + sShortDesc);
    if(oDetail_Fragment != null)
        oDetail_Fragment.setValue(menuID, sShortDesc, sDescription, dRate);

}
```

as per System.out statements, i am getting the value at this level but not able to update the components on details fragment.

detail fragment code is given below.

```
public class Detail_Fragment extends Fragment {


TextView oTVShortDesc, oTVDescription, oTVRate;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Value : onCreateView");
    Bundle oBundle = getArguments();

    View oView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_detail_fragment, null,false);
    oTVShortDesc = (TextView) oView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemShortDesc);
    oTVDescription = (TextView) oView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    oTVRate = (TextView) oView.findViewById(R.id.tvRate);

    return oView;
}

public void setValue(int iMenuID, String sShortDesc, String sDescription, double dRate){
    System.out.println("Value : " + oTVShortDesc);

    TextView oTVShortDesc = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvItemShortDesc);
    System.out.println("Value : " + oTVShortDesc);
    TextView oTVDescription = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    TextView oTVRate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvRate);

    oTVShortDesc.setText(sShortDesc);
    oTVShortDesc.setTag(iMenuID);
    oTVDescription.setText(sDescription);
    oTVRate.setText(String.valueOf(dRate));
}
```

}

while running above code getting following error.

```
    02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817): Process: com.agilissystems.restaurantapp, PID: 25817
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at com.agilissystems.restaurantapp.Detail_Fragment.setValue(Detail_Fragment.java:38)
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at com.agilissystems.restaurantapp.MenuActivity.onItemSelected(MenuActivity.java:139)
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at com.agilissystems.restaurantapp.List_Fragment$MenuExpandableListViewAdapter.getChildView(List_Fragment.java:278)
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
02-07 17:09:59.938: E/AndroidRuntime(25817):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
```

Please advise.

Comment: which one is `Detail_Fragment.setValue(Detail_Fragment.java:38)`

Comment: it is in Detail_Fragment class, which is called in Mainactivity class.

Comment: @Override
 public void onItemSelected(int menuID, String sShortDesc, String sDescription, double dRate) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Detail_Fragment oDetail_Fragment = (Detail_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_Details);
  System.out.println (">> " + oDetail_Fragment);
  System.out.println(">> " + menuID + " >> " + sShortDesc);
  if(oDetail_Fragment != null)
   oDetail_Fragment.setValue(menuID, sShortDesc, sDescription, dRate);
  
 }